# Building an unordered map with tuples as keys

Tags: c++, boost, tuples, unordered-map

In a C++ program with Boost, I am trying to build an unordered map whose keys are tuples of doubles:

```
typedef boost::tuples::tuple<double, double, double, double> Edge;
typedef boost::unordered_map< Edge, int > EdgeMap;
```

Initializing the map completes OK, however, when I try to populate it with keys and values

```
EdgeMap map;
Edge key (0.0, 0.1, 1.1, 1.1);
map[key] = 1;
```

I encounter the following error message:

```
/usr/include/boost/functional/hash/extensions.hpp:176: error: no matching function for call to ‘hash_value(const boost::tuples::tuple<double, double, double, double, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type, boost::tuples::null_type>&)’
```

I presume this is because I need to specify a hash function for the tuple keys. How can I do that?

**EDIT:**

Following the suggestions below, I wrote the following implementation:

```
#include <boost/tuple/tuple.hpp>
#include <boost/unordered_map.hpp>

typedef boost::tuples::tuple<double, double, double, double> Edge;

struct ihash
    : std::unary_function<Edge, std::size_t>
{
    std::size_t operator()(Edge const& e) const
    {
        std::size_t seed = 0;
        boost::hash_combine( seed, e.get<0>() );
        boost::hash_combine( seed, e.get<1>() );
        boost::hash_combine( seed, e.get<2>() );
        boost::hash_combine( seed, e.get<3>() );
        return seed;
    }
};

struct iequal_to
    : std::binary_function<Edge, Edge, bool>
{
    bool operator()(Edge const& x, Edge const& y) const
    {
        return ( x.get<0>()==y.get<0>() &&
                 x.get<1>()==y.get<1>() &&
                 x.get<2>()==y.get<2>() &&
                 x.get<3>()==y.get<3>());
    }
};

typedef boost::unordered_map< Edge, int, ihash, iequal_to > EdgeMap;

int main() {

    EdgeMap map;
    Edge key (0.0, 0.1, 1.1, 1.1);
    map[key] = 1;

    return 0;
}
```

Is it possible to shorten it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need a bit of [front matter](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/doc/html/hash/custom.html). Because of the underlying implementation of `boost::tuples::tuple`, make `Edge` a structure to allow the overloads to resolve correctly. Otherwise, you'll get no matches for

- `boost::hash_value(const Edge &)`
- `operator==(const Edge &, const Edge &)`

Code below:

```
struct Edge {
  Edge(double x1, double x2, double x3, double x4)
    : tuple(x1,x2,x3,x4) {}
  boost::tuples::tuple<double, double, double, double> tuple;
};

// XXX: less than ideal implementation!
bool operator==(const Edge &a, const Edge &b)
{
  return a.tuple.get<0>() == b.tuple.get<0>() &&
         a.tuple.get<1>() == b.tuple.get<1>() &&
         a.tuple.get<2>() == b.tuple.get<2>() &&
         a.tuple.get<3>() == b.tuple.get<3>();
}

// XXX: me too!
std::size_t hash_value(const Edge &e)
{
  std::size_t seed = 0;
  boost::hash_combine(seed, e.tuple.get<0>());
  boost::hash_combine(seed, e.tuple.get<1>());
  boost::hash_combine(seed, e.tuple.get<2>());
  boost::hash_combine(seed, e.tuple.get<3>());
  return seed;
}

typedef boost::unordered_map< Edge, int > EdgeMap;
```

Answer (score 12):

Actually, you could perfectly define a general hash function for `boost::tuple`. The only requirement is that it lives within the same namespace so that it is picked up by ADL.

I am actually surprised that they did not already write one.

```
namespace boost { namespace tuples {

  namespace detail {

    template <class Tuple, size_t Index = length<Tuple>::value - 1>
    struct HashValueImpl
    {
      static void apply(size_t& seed, Tuple const& tuple)
      {
        HashValueImpl<Tuple, Index-1>::apply(seed, tuple);
        boost::hash_combine(seed, tuple.get<Index>());
      }
    };

    template <class Tuple>
    struct HashValueImpl<Tuple,0>
    {
      static void apply(size_t& seed, Tuple const& tuple)
      {
        boost::hash_combine(seed, tuple.get<0>());
      }
    };
  } // namespace detail

  template <class Tuple>
  size_t hash_value(Tuple const& tuple)
  {
    size_t seed = 0;
    detail::HashValueImpl<Tuple>::apply(seed, tuple);
    return seed;
  }

} }
```

Note: I have only proved it correct, I haven't tested it.

Comment: For boost 1.60.0, the "namespace tuple" should be "namespace tuples" to make it work.

Comment: @Val: I think it was the case with all previous versions too actually; thanks :)

Comment: "I have only proved it correct, I haven't tested it." <-- that is also my preferred way to develop code :-)

Answer (score 1):

It's all in the docs...

- http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/doc/html/hash/custom.html
- http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/doc/html/hash/combine.html

You'd need something like:

```
std::size_t hash_value(Edge const& e)
{
    std::size_t seed = 0;
    boost::hash_combine( seed, e.get<0>() );
    boost::hash_combine( seed, e.get<1>() );
    boost::hash_combine( seed, e.get<2>() );
    boost::hash_combine( seed, e.get<3>() );
    return seed;
}
```

... and then you can define:

```
boost::unordered_map< Edge, int, boost::hash< Edge > > EdgeMap;
```

... actually this is default, so it should work without explicit hash definition now:

```
boost::unordered_map< Edge, int > EdgeMap;
```

Answer (score 1):

This code from [Generic hash for tuples in unordered_map / unordered_set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7110301/generic-hash-for-tuples-in-unordered-map-unordered-set) provides magical support for all c++11 tuples of standard hashable types (strings, ints etc).

Unsurprisingly it looks very much like Matthieu M.'s solution above but with no boost dependencies.

Put the code in a header file and include it and unordered sets of tuples will work out of the box:

```
#include <tuple>
namespace std{
    namespace
    {

        // Code from boost
        // Reciprocal of the golden ratio helps spread entropy
        //     and handles duplicates.
        // See Mike Seymour in magic-numbers-in-boosthash-combine:
        //     https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4948780

        template <class T>
        inline void hash_combine(std::size_t& seed, T const& v)
        {
            seed ^= hash<T>()(v) + 0x9e3779b9 + (seed<<6) + (seed>>2);
        }

        // Recursive template code derived from Matthieu M.
        template <class Tuple, size_t Index = std::tuple_size<Tuple>::value - 1>
        struct HashValueImpl
        {
          static void apply(size_t& seed, Tuple const& tuple)
          {
            HashValueImpl<Tuple, Index-1>::apply(seed, tuple);
            hash_combine(seed, get<Index>(tuple));
          }
        };

        template <class Tuple>
        struct HashValueImpl<Tuple,0>
        {
          static void apply(size_t& seed, Tuple const& tuple)
          {
            hash_combine(seed, get<0>(tuple));
          }
        };
    }

    template <typename ... TT>
    struct hash<std::tuple<TT...>> 
    {
        size_t
        operator()(std::tuple<TT...> const& tt) const
        {                                              
            size_t seed = 0;                             
            HashValueImpl<std::tuple<TT...> >::apply(seed, tt);    
            return seed;                                 
        }                                              

    };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using this:

```cpp
#include "boost/functional/hash.hpp"
#include <unordered_map>
#include <tuple>

using Edge = std::tuple<double, double, double, double>;

struct KeyHash {
    std::size_t operator()(const Edge & key) const {
        return boost::hash_value(key);
    }
};

using EdgeMap = std::unordered_map<Edge, int, KeyHash>;
```

please notice I am using `std` for `tuple` and `unordered_map`.

You can see full code with using even lambda on this [Compiler Explorer link](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(fontScale:14,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:14,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:14,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:14,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:14),source:%27%23include+%22boost/functional/hash.hpp%22%0A%23include+%3Cunordered_map%3E%0A%23include+%3Ctuple%3E%0A%0Ausing+Edge+%3D+std::tuple%3Cdouble,+double,+double,+double%3E%3B%0A%0Astruct+KeyHash+%7B%0A++++std::size_t+operator()(const+Edge+%26+key)+const+%7B%0A++++++++return+boost::hash_value(key)%3B%0A++++%7D%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Ausing+EdgeMap+%3D+std::unordered_map%3CEdge,+int,+KeyHash%3E%3B%0A%0A%0Aint+main()+%7B%0A++++auto+hash_fun+%3D+%5B%5D(Edge+const%26+key)+%7B%0A++++++++return+boost::hash_value(key)%3B%0A++++%7D%3B%0A++++using+EdgeMapWithLambda+%3D+std::unordered_map%3CEdge,+int,+decltype(hash_fun)%3E%3B%0A++++return+0%3B%0A%7D%0A%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:43.02872062663185,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang_trunk,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%270%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%271%27,trim:%271%27),fontScale:14,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!((name:boost,ver:%27174%27)),options:%27-Wall+-Weverything+-std%3Dc%2B%2B14+-Wno-c%2B%2B98-compat+-Wno-unused-local-typedef%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27x86-64+clang+(trunk)+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:1,editor:1,fontScale:14,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%231+with+x86-64+clang+(trunk)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:56.97127937336815,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4).

Answer (score 0):

The Boost documentation gives the [required interface](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/doc/html/boost/hash.html). Without knowing more about the values involved, it's hard to say a lot more. Given a key object as input, it has to produce a size_t that's deterministic -- i.e., it's a pure function, where the result depends solely on the input value, so giving the same input will always produce the same hash code.